# How to integrate the above expression ? definite integral

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

How to integrate the above expression. Let I $=$ $$\int_{0}^1 [x^{1/2}/(1+x^{8})^{1/2}]dx$$. I am facing problem to integrate the above expression. First of all I am thinking of writing the expression as $$\int [x^{3}/[(x^{5/2})(1+x^{8})^{1/2}]]dx$$. Now I am thinking of taking $x^{4}$ = u. Now 4×$x^{3}$dx = du. So, $x^{3}$ d$x$ will become du/4. But how to further solve the denominator? Because, in the denominator the term is $[(x^{5/2})×(1+x^{8})^{1/2}]$. Finally the integration is I=$$\int_{0}^1 [1/[4(x^{5/2})(1+x^{8})^{1/2}]]du$$. Please help me out to solve this question.

Comment: *Mathematica*:  $$\frac{2}{3} \, _2F_1\left(\frac{3}{16},\frac{1}{2};\frac{19}{16};-1\right)$$ with hypergeometric function.

Comment: Can you please explain me what is the meaning of F$(3/16,1/2;19/16;-1)$? @DavidG.Stork

Comment: Since I am an undergraduate student so, I don't know these terms.

Comment: Search "Hypergeometric function" on MathWorld.

Comment: Did this come from a textbook, professor, or elsewhere? If you're expected to solve it in the context of a course, maybe there was a typo or mistake in copying?

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to an answer in terms of a [hypergeometric function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunction.html), we'll prove the equality down below.

$$
\bbox[15px,#FFF8FD,border:5px groove #8312FE]{\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{x}{1+x^{8}}}dx=\frac{2}{3}\ _{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{3}{16},\frac{1}{2};\frac{19}{16},-1\right)}
$$

**Proof.** First, we write $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^{8}}}$ as

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x^{8}}} &= \left(1+x^{8}\right)^{\frac{19}{16}-\frac{19}{16}-\frac{1}{2}}\ _{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{19}{16}-\frac{19}{16},\frac{19}{16}-\frac{1}{2};\frac{19}{16};-x^{8}\right) \tag{1}\\
&= \ _{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{19}{16},\frac{1}{2};\frac{19}{16};-x^{8}\right) \tag{2}\\
&= \ _{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{3}{16}+1,\frac{1}{2};\frac{19}{16};-x^{8}\right) \\
&= \ _{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{3}{16},\frac{1}{2};\frac{19}{16};-x^{8}\right)+\frac{\frac{1}{2}\left(-x^{8}\right)}{\frac{19}{16}}\ _{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{3}{16}+1,\frac{1}{2}+1;\frac{19}{16}+1;-x^{8}\right) \tag{3}\\
&= \ _{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{3}{16},\frac{1}{2};\frac{19}{16};-x^{8}\right)-\frac{8x^{8}}{19}\ _{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{19}{16},\frac{3}{2};\frac{35}{16};-x^{8}\right)\,. \\
\end{align}
$$

For $(1)$, it seems like we magically made it up, but it's true from the [definition of the common hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_series)

$$
_{2}F_{1}\left(a,b,c;z\right)=1+\frac{ab}{c}\frac{z}{1!}+\frac{a\left(a+1\right)b\left(b+1\right)}{c\left(c+1\right)}\frac{z^{2}}{2!}+\ldots
$$
where $|z|<1$. After all, if $a=0$, then the series equals $1$ because of all the terms vanishing except the first term. This is sort of how I came up with the $\displaystyle \frac{19}{16}-\frac{19}{16}$. (Well, more like I thought of it from experience.)

In $(2)$, we used the [Hypergeometric Euler transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#The_hypergeometric_differential_equation)

$$
\left(1-z\right)^{c-a-b} \ _{2}F_{1}\left(c-a,c-b;c;z\right)=\ _{2}F_{1}\left(a,b;c;z\right)\,,
$$

and in $(3)$, we used the [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function#Contiguous_function_and_related_identities)

$$
_{2}F_{1}\left(a+1,b;c;z\right)=\frac{bz}{c}\ _{2}F_{1}\left(a+1,b+1;c+1;z\right)+\ _{2}F_{1}\left(a,b;c;z\right)\,.
$$

Getting the non-intuitive algebra out of the way, we're set to evaluate the integral in question. Let the integral equal $\mathcal{I}$. Then

$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I} \overset{(3)}= \int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{x}\ _{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{3}{16},\frac{1}{2};\frac{19}{16};-x^{8}\right)dx-\frac{8}{19}\int_{0}^{1}x^{\frac{17}{2}}\ _{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{19}{16},\frac{3}{2};\frac{35}{16};-x^{8}\right)dx\,.
\end{align}
$$

Using integration by parts on the first integral, we have:

$$
\begin{align}
u &= \ _{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{3}{16},\frac{1}{2};\frac{19}{16};-x^{8}\right) \\
\implies du &= \left(\frac{\frac{3}{16}\cdot\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{19}{16}}\right)\ _{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{3}{16}+1,\frac{1}{2}+1;\frac{19}{16}+1;-x^{8}\right)\left(-8x^{7}\right) \\
&= -\frac{12x^{7}}{19}\ _{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{19}{16},\frac{3}{2};\frac{35}{16};-x^{8}\right) \\
\end{align}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
dv &= \sqrt{x}dx \\
\implies v &= \frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}} \,. \\
\end{align}
$$

Simplifying things nicely, we get

$$
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I} =& \text{ }\left[\ _{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{3}{16},\frac{1}{2};\frac{19}{16};-x^{8}\right)\cdot\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}\right]_{0}^{1} \\
\require{cancel} &\cancelto{0}{-\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2}{3}x^{\frac{3}{2}}\left(-\frac{12x^{7}}{19}\ _{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{19}{16},\frac{3}{2};\frac{35}{16};-x^{8}\right)\right)dx-\frac{8}{19}\int_{0}^{1}x^{\frac{17}{2}}\ _{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{19}{16},\frac{3}{2};\frac{35}{16};-x^{8}\right)dx} \\
\require{cancel} =& \ _{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{3}{16},\frac{1}{2};\frac{19}{16};-\left(1\right)^{8}\right)\cdot\frac{2}{3}\left(1\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}-\cancelto{0}{\ _{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{3}{16},\frac{1}{2};\frac{19}{16};-\left(0\right)^{8}\right)\cdot\frac{2}{3}\left(0\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}}\,. \\
\end{align}
$$

We finally end with

$$
\bbox[15px,#E0EFFF,border:5px groove #0058B3]{\int_{0}^{1}\sqrt{\frac{x}{1+x^{8}}}dx=\frac{2}{3}\ _{2}F_{1}\left(\frac{3}{16},\frac{1}{2};\frac{19}{16};-1\right)}
$$

and we're done! $\blacksquare$

<sub>**Cheers! (^///^)**</sub>